# Pgfplots axis x line = bottom changes plot content

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, dateplot

I'd like to disable the top border of the plot.
To do so, I used `axis x line = bottom`.
However, this changed the plots content (the left most and right most bar are now hidden).
How can I achieve this without changing the plot content?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{
axis x line = bottom,
every x tick label/.append style={rotate=45,anchor=east,yshift=-0.3cm},
}

\begin{filecontents}{minimal.csv}
Datum;A;B;X;Y
2017-05-01;2.92;4.08;135861;14767
2017-06-01;2.92;4.08;135861;14767
2017-07-01;2.85;4.85;137600;96389
2017-08-01;2.78;5.42;137032;16351
2017-09-01;2.75;5.40;108018;56753
2017-10-01;2.66;4.97;156561;40026
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  ybar,
  xtick=data,
]
\addplot table [x = Datum, y = X, col sep=semicolon] {minimal.csv}; 
\addplot table [x = Datum, y = Y, col sep=semicolon] {minimal.csv}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try the starred version: `axis x line* = bottom`

Comment: Thanks, this works, if you add an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the starred version: `axis x line*=bottom`. From pgfplots manual:

> The starred versions . . . line* only affect the axis lines, without
>   correcting the positions of axis labels, tick lines or other keys
>   which are (possibly) affected by a changed axis line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz, xcolor, graphicx
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% <- added, current version is 1.15
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{
axis x line* = bottom,% <- changed
every x tick label/.append style={rotate=45,anchor=east,yshift=-0.3cm},
}

\begin{filecontents}{minimal.csv}
Datum;A;B;X;Y
2017-05-01;2.92;4.08;135861;14767
2017-06-01;2.92;4.08;135861;14767
2017-07-01;2.85;4.85;137600;96389
2017-08-01;2.78;5.42;137032;16351
2017-09-01;2.75;5.40;108018;56753
2017-10-01;2.66;4.97;156561;40026
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  ybar,
  xtick=data,
]
\addplot table [x = Datum, y = X, col sep=semicolon] {minimal.csv}; 
\addplot table [x = Datum, y = Y, col sep=semicolon] {minimal.csv}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that it is recommended to add a `compat` after loading `pgfplots`. Current version is 1.15.